# Convert time zone of XML parsed time and date with moment.js

Tags: javascript, xml, date, time, momentjs

I'm parsing a XML file with Javascript and I would like to convert a date to my local time zone using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) but I'm stuck. The basic parsing consists of getting the date:

```
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("Date")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

Which generates something like `31/12/2016 23:00`. With moment.js it's possible to format the date like this:

```
var utcDate = moment.utc('31/12/2016 23:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm');
var localDate = utcDate.local();
document.write(localDate);
```

Which writes `01/01/2017 01:00` in my current time zone. But I can't figure out how to use the method above with the parsing. Tried modifying the variable but only getting "Invalid date" as a result.

```
var utcDate = moment.utc('x[i].getElementsByTagName("Date")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm');
var localDate = utcDate.local();
document.write (localDate);
```

Does anyone have any tips? Might be other solutions than using moment.js but it seemed like the best and most flexible option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've put your XML traversal inside a string. That traversal won't happen if it's not actual javascript. Additionally, moment.js will try to parse that literal string as a date, NOT the value from that traversal.

```
'x[i].getElementsByTagName("Date")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue'
```

You need to unquote your traversal to get its value, then feed that to moment.js.

```
var utcDate = moment.utc(x[i].getElementsByTagName("Date")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm');
```

Comment: Ah it was that simple, working like a charm now. Thank you!